# How to restrict text length in FCKeditor 2.6?

Tags: fckeditor

How to restrict text length in FCKeditor 2.6? I found plugin for 2.3 version, but it doesn't work

Comment: Please expand on this question. What was the plug-in? And what are the specifics of "it doesn't work"? Please provide a code snippet as well. It's possible that you're not using the plug-in correctly and some SOer might spot a bug.

Comment: I found the new version of this plug-in. It works perfectly for FCKeditor 2.6
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2681808&group_id=75348&atid=737639

Comment: OK. Please answer your own question. It may be helpful to others. I'll amke sure and vote up if you do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the new version of this plug-in. It works perfectly for FCKeditor 2.6

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2681808&group_id=75348&atid=737639